# Centos 7/1503 -- Getting Error setting up base repository during installation

Tags: centos, installation, centos7, usb-flash-drive

I've created bootable USB flash drive using recommended [LiveUSB Creator](https://fedorahosted.org/liveusb-creator/) using `CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-1503-01.iso`.

Now being at **Installation Summary** screen I'm getting *Error setting up base repository*. When I click on **Verify** at **Installation Source** screen I get *This media is not good to install from*. Rather cryptic error message...

I've also tried switch to **On the network** and insert `http://mirrors.kernel.org/centos/7/os/x86_x64` with no success.

Additional info: Installing on HP EliteBook 8540w

Comment: Reboot and choose "Test this media..."

Comment: When choose _Test this media..._, it seems that it doesn't test anything at all. Now I've noticed this message during boot process:

_A TMP error occurred attempting to read a pcr value_

But it doesn't explain why even network repository doesn't work.

Comment: Created on another piece of USB pendrive. Same results....

Comment: Do you actually have a good copy of the ISO?

Comment: It seem's to be. Getting MD5 sum 
186b049a88b18f7d43e03eed72247c76 as I can read on http://ftp.cvut.cz/centos/7/isos/x86_64/md5sum.txt

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have an error in the mirror URL (and extra x at x64) it should be `http://mirrors.kernel.org/centos/7/os/x86_64`.

Comment: Fixed it for me, today (without clicking the checkbox for mirror link). I had tried three other URLs before, from different FAQs and guides.

Comment: tried, it didn't help me

Comment: In my case I was installing CentOS from a netinsall iso on a VirtualBox VM. I would have expect the installer to provide a default source but it didn't, using this url as the source solved my issue.

Comment: **Everyone Please make sure  your interface is enabled**, then only it can contact mirrors. I think in installation step they should give a warning to  enable this !!!!

Answer (score 2):

Do not use LiveUSB creator, it doesn't work with this release of CentOS.

I had the same problem, I recreated the USB flash drive using dd under Linux ( `dd bs=4M if=CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-1503-01.iso of=/dev/sd[letter of your USB drive]` ), and it worked like a charm.

If you do not have access to a Linux machine, you need to report this problem to LiveUSB-Creator developers and/or CentOS developers.

Answer (score 2):

when you install centos 7 on network, you may config installation source.

when you input the url under the label 'On the network:', you'll see the check box already checked that means 'This URL refers to a mirror list' , disable that.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem. It is working after I switch to [Win32 Disk Imager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/).

Please try using another USB ISO burner. It should work. There is [a list of working programs](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/InstallFromUSBkey) for the task.